# How to use ROS urdf package in Drake?

Tags: drake

I'm new to Drake.And I want to use my robot model which is a **ROS urdf package** converted from SolidWorks plugin.I've tried to use

```py
builder = DiagramBuilder()
plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodySceneGraph(builder,0.0)
parser = Parser(plant)
pkg_map = parser.package_map()
pkg_map.AddPackageXml("myxmlfilepath")
robot_file = "my_urdf_file_path"
robot = parser.AddModelFromFile(robot_file, "robot")
```

But I got an error`RuntimeError:The WaveFront obj file has no faces`  in the last line.I try to use ROS to display and it works well.  My urdf file has some **.stl** format mesh file for visual and collision. I see some comments [here](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/tree/master/examples/pr2), so I guess Drake maybe can't deal with **.stl** in a default way so far.What should I do except manually converting **.stl** mesh file to **.obj** file? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: After I substitute **.stl** file with manually converted **.obj**file, this Runtime Error disappear. But I still wonder is there other way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted in your comment above, once you converted your STL file to an OBJ file, you were able to load your URDF file.

This is because Drake does not yet support loading STL (or DAE) meshes at runtime; they must be converted (either manually as you had done, or via the build system). For more info, please see: 
https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/2941

In that issue, I've referenced your post as a motivator towards adding additional mesh support.

Thanks!

Comment: Oh,I see. Thanks for your help.