# How do you visualise your ROS URDF on the Drake visualizer?

Tags: drake

Drake noob here.
I tried running the `drake_visualizer` and `geometry_inspector` with my own ROS generated URDF that depicts and experimental setup with two UR10s. This throws two errors

- PackageMap is not able to resolve certain mesh files of extension `*.STL` and `*.DAE`. This has been well catalogued in [this](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/2941) link.
- And ROS paths of the sort `package://blah/blah` do not seem to be resolved as well. I know this because the console throws the following error

```
Couldn't find package 'blah' in the supplied packagepath: PackageMap:
 [EMPTY!]
```

In another [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65101327/how-to-use-ros-urdf-package-in-drake) question, one of the authors of the Drake repo suggested we can transform the `.stl` files during build time. I tried searching for how you can exactly do this but couldn't find anything. I have the feeling that I am missing something fundamental here. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: To be clear -- is the error coming from the `geometry_inspector` instance or the `drake_visualizer` instance?  For the `geometry_inspector`, you can using the `PackageMap` class to add additional paths.  https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_package_map.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Russ's comment, what you need to do is the following

```
parser = Parser(plant)
parser.package_map().PopulateFromFolder("path/to/folder/containing/package.xml")
parser.AddModelFromFile("your.urdf")
```

There are many ways to populate the package map, as linked in Russ's comment